# AwsCustomResource Access Values with Different Paths

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to use two different SDK services within an AwsCustomResource, one with the OnCreate action, and one with the OnUpdate. This is because the first time this runs, the OnUpdate doesn't return anything because I have yet to deploy the resources, and I rely on a parameter that is stored to get this information. Is there any way to do what I'm attempting?

```js
const getRestApiBasePathMappings = new custom_resources.AwsCustomResource(this, `GetRestApiBasePathMappings`, {
  policy: custom_resources.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
    new iam.PolicyStatement({ actions: ['apigateway:GET'], resources: ['*'] }),
    new iam.PolicyStatement({ actions: ['ssm:GET'], resources: ['*'] }),
  ]),
  onCreate: {
    service: 'SSM',
    action: 'getParameter',
    parameters: {
      Name: `${activeStageParameter}/${this.environmentName}`,
    },
    physicalResourceId: custom_resources.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
    outputPaths: ['Parameter.Value'],
  },
  onUpdate: {
    service: 'APIGateway',
    action: 'getBasePathMapping',
    parameters: { basePath: 'rest', domainName: domainName },
    physicalResourceId: custom_resources.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
    outputPaths: ['stage'],
  },
});

const restStage = getRestApiBasePathMappings.getResponseField(//what do I do here?);
```

Basically, both of the outputPaths will get me to a single string since they have a different key. I'm guessing this is where I'm wrong.

Comment: No, you should instead simply declare a dependency so that this custom resource is invoked after your API GW is provisioned.

Comment: Yea, Ideally I would like to do that, but this is used for blue/green deployment and this custom resource is used to determine what stage is active and to deploy to the other stage to test and eventually swap to. The problem is during the first deployment of the API so there is no "active" stage because I haven't created the mappings yet.

Comment: Right, I'm saying you need to declare a dependency so that this custom resource is invoked after the mappings have been created. You provision them with CDK, right?

Comment: Yea, so my question was on the possibility of having dynamic or empty response field, to see if it was possible. Which is isn't and I have a chicken and egg problem. Basically it is this

1. Check to see if blue or green is the active deployment by basePathMapping Check
2. Deploy to inactive base path
3. Do functional/integration tests on inactive.
4. If succeed swap.

The problem was on the first deployment #1 can't happen. So I changed how I do my assert to a lambda so that if the request type is Create, I know I'm creating my APIs for the first time and skip getting the base path.